# maximum stack size in prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
 <script>
        function employee(fname, lname) {
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.fullname = function () {
                return this.fname + " " + this.lname;
            }
            
        }
        employee.prototype.sendtoserver = function () {
            $.post("/abc.aspx",this).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
        var johnny = new employee("johnny", "hkko");
        
    </script>
```

When i call the prototype function on button click like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="johnny.sendtoserver()" value="fddfdfdf"/>`
```

maximum stack size reached and when i debug i found it is called multiple times one with johny and other with window.

Comment: besides a small error (you have nothing after the comma here: `$.post("/abc.aspx", )` ) this seems to be [completely ok](http://jsfiddle.net/w80f63ke/). Are you sure you aren't missing some information?

Comment: Do you find that the data is actually sent to the server at all? I would be very careful with use of 'this' in javascript.

Comment: Yes data is sent to the server. But memory stack size error occured

Comment: Does it work better if you just pass plain data and not an object with a function, e.g. `$.post("/abc.aspx",this.fname)`?